# Open password protected PDF file without asking for password in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, pdf

In one of my iPad application I have created PDF report and show it in web view and user can email that report to customer. Following code I have used for creating the report.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"owner", kCGPDFContextOwnerPassword, @"user", kCGPDFContextUserPassword, kCFBooleanFalse, kCGPDFContextAllowsCopying, kCFBooleanFalse, kCGPDFContextAllowsPrinting,  nil];
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(thefilePath, CGRectZero, dictionary);
```

Password protection is working fine for me.

But our requirement is, when user open that PDF file in web view in the application then It should not ask for Password. It will only ask for the password when user emailed that PDF file to customer and that customer tried to view it.

So I want to know whether there is any option so that we can open the PDF file by providing password programmatically inside the application when user view it in web view.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have resolve the issue and created own pdf viewer using scroll view and views.

I have first unlocked the PDF view and then shown that pdf view using the reference of below url:

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/06/rendering-pdf-is-easier-than-you-thought/

Then assigned the zoom in/out to scroll view. Its working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** : You `cannot` `open` `password protected` `PDF` in `UIWebView` unless you `unlock` it.

Solution is need to first `unlock` use `CGPDFDocumentUnlockWithPassword` :

```
 CGPDFDocumentUnlockWithPassword(doc, pass).
```

You could then generate an `unlocked version` as `NSData` in `memory` and `load` that into the `web view` (not password protected at this point).

Comment: In my application I can open password protected file in UIWebview. I tried your solution but don't know how to convert CGPDFDocumentRef to NSData.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a NSData object out of the CFURL of which you create the CGPDFDocumentRef if that's what you want:

```
let url = yourCFURL as NSURL
let data = NSData(contentsOfUrl: url)
```